# Is it necessary to check typeof this == 'function' when implementing our own call method?

Tags: javascript

Here is an implementation of my own `call` method:

```js
Function.prototype.myCall = function(thisArg,...args){
    if(typeof this != 'function'){
        throw new Error('myCall must be called via a function')
    }
    thisArg = thisArg ? Object(thisArg) : globalThis
    thisArg.fn = this
    const res = thisArg.fn(...args)
    delete thisArg.fn
    return res
}
```

But I'm no sure if I should check `typeof this != 'function'` here. Yes, the caller of `myCall` must be a function. But even if I don't check this, there is still an error thrown. For example, when executing `{a:1}.myCall()`, there will be an error saying {a:1}.myCall is not a function. And since I have got this error, the `throw new Error('myCall must be called via a function')` can't actually be executed.

Comment: You can try `({a:1}).myCall()`. Your `throw` code has been executed.

Comment: Yes, you'll need the check, because an object might have been subclassed from `Function`. I'm not sure if you even can fully emulate `call`, see [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.call) to find out how `call` should be implemented.

Comment: @namgold No. the `throw` code hasn't been executed since another error has been thrown firstly which saying that {(intermediate value)}.myCall is not a function

Comment: @Teemu If  an object have been subclassed from `Function`, then it can call `myCall` method (therefore no error thrown saying something is not a function) but it can't pass the `typeof` check because typeof this equals object instead of function, right? So I still need to add the check.

Comment: Something like that, I didn't actually test it. However, the standard implementation makes the check in any case. It's notable, that the native `call` method can bind the function to `null` too, yours fails in that.

Comment: In strict mode the `thisArg` can even be a primitive -- it will not be wrapped.

Comment: @Teemu What does binding the function to `null` mean? The `myCall` method can also let `this` being `null` in which case it will actually be a global Object (like `window`).

Comment: Yes, but then the function execution is bound to the context of `window` instead of `null`.

Comment: @Teemu No. I mean it should be `window` here.The MDN says that " In non-strict mode, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be converted to objects."

Comment: You said the native `call` method can bind the function to null too.Maybe what you mean is in strict mode?

Comment: Yep. It looks like, that I've forgotten that small detail, as I've not written scripts in sloppy mode for years = ).

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` check is necessary because an object may be subclassed from `Function`.

If I remove the check like this:

```js
Function.prototype.myCall = function(thisArg,...args){
    thisArg = thisArg ? Object(thisArg) : globalThis
    thisArg.fn = this
    const res = thisArg.fn(...args)
    delete thisArg.fn
    return res
}
```

And there is an object like this:

```js
const obj = Object.create(Function.prototype)
obj.myCall()
```

Although the `obj` actually isn't a function, it can invoke `myCall` because it was subclassed from `Function`. And since I didn't check if `this`(in this case the `obj`) is really a function, the `thisArg.fn` call would throw an error.